# i can't use exceljs api

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, exceljs

I want to use excelJs in vueJs 3. but their example code doesn't work properly.
exceljs is 4.3.0

my code is

```
import Excel from "exceljs";

export default {
    methods: {
      greet(event) {
                const options = {
          filename: './streamed-workbook.xlsx',
          useStyles: true,
          useSharedStrings: true
        };
        const workbook = new Excel.stream.xlsx.WorkbookWriter(options);
               ...

 }
}
```

but approaching here row,
`const workbook = new Excel.stream.xlsx.WorkbookWriter(options);`

debugger throws an error =>
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'xlsx')

`const workbook = new Excel.stream.xlsx.WorkbookWriter(options);`
should work well.

i don't understand this is just copy of the document guide.
(https://github.com/exceljs/exceljs#streaming-xlsx)

Comment: the stream functionality appears to be for a node environment only, read the [section below it](https://github.com/exceljs/exceljs#browser)  "A portion of this library has been isolated and tested for use within a browser environment. Due to the streaming nature of the workbook reader and workbook writer, these have not been included. Only the document based workbook may be used"

Comment: ok, thanks a lot.  I missed it.